# Pulseaudio device name changes

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulse-audio

I would like to set my default sink/source in pulseaudio but the name constanly changes.
It's either

- `alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.stereo-fallback` or
- `alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo`

and hence `pulseaudio.service` fails when I have the respective other in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

Is there any generic way? Even a wildcard would help.

Comment: have a look at pavucontrol. It allows setting the default audio device.

Comment: For my personal belongings that would be sufficient but this is to be part of a bigger project and needs to be kind of bullet proof (and headless as well). I don't know `pavucontrol`s internal logic nor where the preferences are being saved.